# CAS: 6.2.0-snapshot Error with cas-server-support-json-service-registry in JBoss

Tags: java, cas, java-11, apereo

**Class Not Found Error: org.apereo.cas.services.ServiceRegistry]: Factory method 'jsonServiceRegistry' 
 threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/nio/file/SensitivityWatchEventModifier**

I am using Cas-war-overlay(6.2.0-snapshot). Have included the
*compile "org.apereo.cas:cas-server-support-json-service-registry:${project.'cas.version'}"*
in the gradle dependencies section. Everything was working fine till 16/04/2020. Suddenly getting this error since today.

StackTrace:

````
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/nio/file/SensitivityWatchEventModifier
        at deployment.cas.war//org.apereo.cas.util.io.PathWatcherService.<init>(PathWatcherService.java:67)
        at deployment.cas.war//org.apereo.cas.services.resource.AbstractResourceBasedServiceRegistry.enableDefaultWatcherService(AbstractResourceBasedServiceRegistry.java:183)
        at deployment.cas.war//org.apereo.cas.config.JsonServiceRegistryConfiguration.jsonServiceRegistry(JsonServiceRegistryConfiguration.java:69)
        at deployment.cas.war//org.apereo.cas.config.JsonServiceRegistryConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b4c519e.CGLIB$jsonServiceRegistry$0(<generated>)
        at deployment.cas.war//org.apereo.cas.config.JsonServiceRegistryConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b4c519e$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$17923b01.invoke(<generated>)
        at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
        at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
        at deployment.cas.war//org.apereo.cas.config.JsonServiceRegistryConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b4c519e.jsonServiceRegistry(<generated>)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I was managed to solve this issue by modifying  jboss-deployment-structure.xml. Added below code:

```
  <dependencies>
            <system export="true">
                <paths>
                    <path name="com/sun/nio/file"/>
                </paths>
            </system>
        </dependencies>
```